# localstorage to send value to a file in iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, local-storage

File 1 has the following script in it:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#buttonClass").click(function() {
        getValueUsingClass();
    });
    });

function getValueUsingClass(){

    var chkArray = [];

    $(".chk:checked").each(function() {
        chkArray.push($(this).val());
    });

    var selected;
    selected = chkArray.join(',') ;

        localStorage.setItem("imgid",selected);

        var varmodal = document.getElementById('myinfomodal');
        var span = document.getElementsByClassName('infoclose')[0];

        varmodal.style.display = "block";

        span.onclick = function() {
        varmodal.style.display = "none";
    }

}
```

The above script opens the following div/iframe (also in File 1):

```
<div id="myinfomodal" class="infomodal">
    <div class="infomodal-content">
    <button class="infoclose">Close</button>
    <iframe id="frameid" src="https://outzeal.com/zp2.php" width="100%" height="500px;" style="border:none;"></iframe>
    </div>
    </div>
```

The variable ***selected*** is supposed to be transferred through localStorage to a second file. The script in the second file is:

```
 window.onload = function () {
 var a = localStorage.getItem("imgid");
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
 if(a == 0){
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "no image selected";
  }
  }
```

Please click on this link *(not available anymore)* for a demo. After clicking on the image the image opens in a modal div. Selecting the check box and clicking on the "Cart icon" opens the div and the iframe file but does not show the value of the variable ***selected*** (probably because the function should run after window.onload happens and that has never happened here). If the second file is opened separately (window.onload happens here) the value is shown. I want the value of ***selected*** in the modal div. How can that be done? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has nothing wrong, **it's just a cache problem**: I copied your code on my local, of course using zp2.html instead zp2.php (I don't have a PHP server) and it seems to works pretty good: I've got both "no image selected" and "skiing/001", instead on the remote I don't see anything (I think it's because a previous behaviour of zp2.p.

Try to edit your zp2.php and use anonymous navigation, or disable the cache on your browser.

PS: Anyway if you change the value of the checkbox after push the button, the iframe will show the first value because you're using window.onload on zp2.php... **If you need a popup you don't need to use iframe and another server page**, neither localweb, you can use a global javascript variable.

Comment: Thanks, I checked in incognito mode along with disabling cache but the result is the same i.e. variable value seen only if zp2.htm is opened in a new window. When it is opened in the popup iframe in zp1.htm the var value is not there. I agree I can remove the iframe in the pop up div and instead put the content of zp2 there, but i want to avoid stuffing the zp2 code (which is more than what is shown in this example) in the pop up div.

Comment: You can put yor browser in incognoti mode, go to https://www.outzeal.com/zp1.php, check/uncheck the checkbox and press the button cart, and you'll see the update on https://www.outzeal.com/zp2.php. I just tried, so it's not a metter of local environment.

Your only problem is that your status not update along with your checkbox.

Comment: Ok, i think i'll just dump the zp2 code in the div instead of iframe since that is an acceptable workaround. Thanks for the help. Since I mentioned the links for zp1 and zp2 in my post, will it be considered negative in this forum if I delete zp1 and zp2 files now from my directories?

Comment: mmm I don't think so, since it's a vey personal-architectural problem and not a generic question about localweb